# cakePHP - Simple insert statements taking long time to execute

Tags: cakephp

We are using the cakePHP framework and have deployed the application on our product environment. We have noticed that insert statements are taking a long time to execute. Sometimes a simple insert statement takes 6 seconds which is way too much.

We have switched the persistent key to true in database.php and it seems to improve alot, but still, sometimes queries do take 2 to 3 seconds. Is it a good idea to have this switched on?

Any advice on why and how we can improve execution times?

Thanks

Regards
Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

Does it take long on the local dev environment? Set debug to 2 in core.php to get an sqldump that will show you each SQL statement and time for each.  Maybe you have too many joins?

Remember to add the sql dump element to your layout:

```
<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Costa the problem was related to some sort of I/O hardware problem on the production server. Thanks your interest.